# Error with Quaternion.FromToRotation in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get multiple errors whenever I run this code:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3(0, 0, 270));
```

Can you suggest a fix for this code?

Errors:

> Expression denotes a type', where avariable', value' ormethod group' was expected
>
> The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Quaternion.FromToRotation(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)` has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument #1' cannot convertobject' expression to type `UnityEngine.Vector3`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's crossposted here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110659/error-with-quaternion-fromtorotation-in-unity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using C#, you should use `new Vector3()` instead of `Vector3`